# How to Load Webview in DetailViewController using URL Sent by MasterViewController using Apple Master-Detail Template

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiwebview, master-detail

ebview is not displaying or loading in detail page.

I am begineer to IOS development and i am developing project using Master-Detail template.

My requirement is

Master view (Menu --> Left side window)
Detail View (Right side window)

when a user selects the item in left side window menu, A corresponding URL received from master left menu should be loaded in UIWebview in detail view page in right side window. For me webview is not loading.

Please help me solve this problem and provide sample code or reference URL to solve this issue

Thanks in advance,

Uday.G

Answer (score 0):

It will be something like this:
In MasterViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *object = [_objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//assuming you keep the url list in _objects
    self.detailViewController loadPage:object];
}
```

in DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)loadPage:(NSString*)urlString
{
  NSURLRequest* request=[NSURlRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL urlWithString:urlString]];
 [self.webView loadRequest:request]; //assuming your UIWebView is property named webView
}
```

And I strongly suggest you reading some tutorials about UITableViewController as you can't go far without understanding it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I'll try to implement the same in my projct.